# parent class is being searched in wrong location

Tags: php, autoload, directory-structure, fat-free-framework

I am trying to custom create an MVC folder structure on top of the fat-free framework.I have a `controllers` folder with two files, `base.php` and `index.php`. Now I am trying to load the index file like:

```
$f3->route('GET /','Index->index');
```

But I get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'controllers\Base' not found
```

code for base.php:

```
<?php
namespace controllers;
class Base extends \Prefab {
    protected $f3;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->f3 = \Base::instance();
    }
}
```

code for index.php

```
<?php
namespace controllers;
class Index extends Base {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($f3, $params) {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `controllers` folder should be a subfolder of your `AUTOLOAD` folder. Something like this:

```
- autoload
 |- controllers
   |- base.php
   |- index.php
- lib
 |- base.php
- index.php
```

And your root index.php would look like this:

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','autoload/');
$f3->route('GET /','controllers\Index->index');
```

PS: what happened in your example is that the `controllers` folder being declared as the autoload folder, `base.php` and `index.php` were seen as part of the root namespace.